# PayPal simple upload cart using one button - why is shopping cart empty?

Tags: php, upload, paypal, shopping-cart

I'm trying to upload a cart with the following code, but when the user hits the "buy now" button, then instead of showing PayPal's order summary page where the user can sign in to pay, I get an error that says `Your shopping cart is empty.`

This is my code, what's wrong with it?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<a href='cart.php?type=current' class='buttonlink previous'>Edit Order</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='checkout4_confirm.php' class='buttonlink next'>Submit Order</a>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="JRECLRTYAJDKY">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXX@XXX.XXX">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="<?php echo $order_number; ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1"> 
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely being caused by the fact that you are creating a hosted button from your account, but then you are making modifications to the code.  If you are going to do this, you need to create a clear text, non hosted button.

When creating the button from within your account, uncheck the option on step 2 to save button at PayPal.  Then once the code is generated, click the link to remove code protection.  This will create a clear text non hosted button.  Then you should be able to modify the button.

Comment: but then it won't be secure, will it?

Comment: It depends on your description of secure.  It will still be secure in respect to the customers credit card information.  It would not be secure in respect to that someone could right click the page and view the souce code.  Save it, and then modify the amount, and process a payment for a lesser amount.  Merchants that use non hosted buttons, simply have thier system perform checks with IPN and refund transactions that were not for the full amount.  You could also create the hosted buttons on the fly, and pass your info over at that time instead of modifying it afterwards.